# Issue with float:left

Tags: css, css-float

I have a php page which shows profiles of users from a database.

I have a division of class 'member' for each profile.

If i use float-left for .member class, the content division for the profiles does not expand and profiles are shown outside the container. You can see in the following screenshot.

http://s14.postimage.org/failytjs1/With_Float.png

However, If i don't use float-left for .member class, the content division for the profiles does expand according to the php and profiles are shown inside the container. You can see in the following screenshot.

http://s14.postimage.org/owc6f4axt/Without_Float.png

Comment: Code? What style do the containers hold?

Comment: please post your code,so that we can help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a `overflow: hidden;` to the parent element of the `div`s with class 'member'. If the parent element has a height, remove it.

Comment: The float has to be stopped at the end. You can end it with adding an invisible element with css `clear: both;` or you can set `overflow: hidden;` to the parent element to end the floating.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `<div style="clear: both;"></div>`